# Java doc missing for inherited method in enunciate

Tags: java, enunciate

I have following class hierarchy. When I generate javadoc for subclass, the generated doc does not contain java doc comment for the method inherited from the super class.

```
public class SuperClass
{

  /**
   Something interesting.
  */
  public void SuperClassMethod() {

   }
...
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass
{

}
```

I am generating docs for SubClass. The doc for the method from the SuperClass are empty.

Comment: A bit of shot in the dark, but have you tried adding `{@inheritDoc}` in the javadoc of the subclass method?

Comment: I am not over-ridding the method in sub class, just inheriting. So, I cannot do {@inheritDoc}.

Comment: public class SuperClassMethod(); I assume you mean   public void SuperClassMethod();?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I updated the method signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In enunciate.xml file, specify the following tag for the super class

```
<api-import class="com.superclassPackage.superClassName" />
```

This works for the case when superClass belongs to some other project as well.